# Only one row can be inserted into SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to extract data from JSON and put it into the database.

This is where I inserted:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length(); i++) {

            //extraction to get "time" and "weather_description"
            //............

            //insertion:

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            //values.put(WeatherEntry._ID,i);
            values.put(WeatherEntry.DATE_COLUMN, time);
            values.put(WeatherEntry.DESCRIPTION_COLUMN, weather_description);

            getContentResolver().insert(WeatherEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class WeatherDb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  static final String DATABASE_NAME = "weather.db";

  public WeatherDb(Context context) {
      super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
      String WEATHER_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+ WeatherEntry.WEATHER_TABLE_NAME+" ("+
              WeatherEntry._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
              WeatherEntry.DATE_COLUMN+" TEXT, "+
              WeatherEntry.DESCRIPTION_COLUMN+" TEXT );";

      sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(WEATHER_QUERY);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

  }
}
```

> Only the first row (with `_ID=0`) was able to go into the database.

I also got the error message:
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: weather._id (code 1555)`

Comment: show us how you call the insert method

Comment: i guess time and weather_description in first piece of code are same for every insert..?

Comment: How you checked **Only the first row (with _ID=0) was able to go into the database** ..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran ,By using `select * from weather;` (`weather` is the table name).

Comment: Change your create query as AUTOINCREMENT form id field like this 
 **WeatherEntry._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "**, and remove the code which you inserting id and check

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran , Still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any error..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran The same error

Comment: Could you update your code in your question, And one more thing delete your app and do fresh install and check

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `AUTOINCREMENT` like this instead on inserting `i` :

```
WeatherEntry._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"
```